# Nodemailer sends email witthout error, but I received nothing

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

```
function sendMail(uid) {
    var emailRef = admin.database().ref("users/"+uid+"/email");
    emailRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        var email = snapshot.val();
        if (email !== null && email != undefined && email != "") {
            fs.readFile('Key/mail.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                objMail = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log("MAIL OBJECT:"+ objMail.text);
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://email%40mywebsite.com:'+objMail.text+'@smtp.gmail.com');
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: '"Notification" <notification@mywebsite.com>',
                    to: email,
                    subject: 'Notification', 
                    html: "<h1>Test</h1>"
                };

                // send mail with defined transport object
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                    if(error){
                        console.log("NOOOO: "+error);
                        res.send(false);
                    } 
                    else {
                        console.log("YESSS");
                        res.send(true);
                    }
                });
            });   
        }
        else {
            res.send(false);
        }
    });
}
```

---

All values are printed out correctly:

1) email is the correct one used by the user.

2) objMail.text is the application specific password to use the email address to send the email. (You would use the Less Secure Apps toggle if you didn't use 2FA).

3) "YESSSS" is printed at the end.

The email nodemailer is supposed to send the message to is one I control to test the package. I got it to work on another project and pretty much reused everything to my knowledge.

Would you know what is causing the email to not be received/sent ?

Comment: try printing info object, probably there is more information so as to what happened.

Comment: @awd What do you mean by "info object" ?

Comment: the callback function `function(error, info)`

Comment: @awd No useful Info :/ All seems to have worked perfectly: INFO: {"accepted":["email@gmail.com"],"rejected":[],"response":"250 2.0.0 OK 1507052875 w51sm11409703edd.60 - gsmtp","envelope":{"from":"notification@website.com","to":["email@gmail.com"]},"messageId":"<f9615e80-b7c2-f486-c257-52eb28715202@website.com>"}

Comment: @awd It actually worked :/ I was just receiving it in my spam folder :( Hmm, how do I fix this ?