# NodeMailer Gmail API in AWS Lambda not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer with gmail API to send mails.

Following code :-

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'xx@usr.com',
        pass: 'xxx'
    }
});
console.log("Starting");
await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'xx@google.com',
    to: 'xx@google.com',
    subject: 'Hello !',
    text: "Hello"
}, function(data, info){

});
```

Code is working perfectly on local & sending mails.

But, when used inside lambda nothing is happening. Function getting executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The error would probably be in the **(1)** code, **(2)** IAM permissions (for SES, see  [Nodemailer SES doc](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/), [Connecting to the Amazon SES SMTP Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html) and [SES FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/)) or 
 **(3)** networking (if lambda runs from private VPC and networking isn't fully configured).

*Or maybe its working fine (see @TheProgrammer's comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549581/nodemailer-sends-email-witthout-error-but-i-received-nothing#comment80055439_46549581))*

**To view and understand the error, try the following:**

1. **Adding logging to the error callback** of sendMail method ([see this](https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/#examples)):

   ```
   transporter.sendMail({
       from: 'sender@example.com',
       to: 'recipient@example.com',
       subject: 'Message',
       text: 'I hope this message gets delivered!'
   }, (err, info) => {
       console.log(info.envelope);
       console.log(info.messageId);
       console.log(err);
   });
   ```
2. **Viewing the error in CloudWatch logs** (accessed directly from *View logs in CloudWatch*, [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html))